# Converting a simple folder to shared folder in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I just made a program in Qt that creates a folder in a specific diretory.

the code is:

```
QDir directory;

    directory.mkdir("Sample");
```

my problem is how could i convert the folder to a shared folder using Qt codes?

Or is there a way to create a shared folder using Qt??

Comment: What do you mean by 'shared' folder?

Comment: i mean setting it to a shared folder where it can be access in a network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share a directory using [`NetShareAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525384.aspx). As far as I know, Qt doesn't provide anything with the same basic capability as `NetShareAdd`.

Edit: here's a quite bit of demo code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>

int main() { 

    SHARE_INFO_2 info = {0};

    info.shi2_netname = L"test_share";
    info.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE;
    info.shi2_permissions = ACCESS_ALL;
    info.shi2_max_uses = -1;
    info.shi2_path = L"C:\\a\\b\\c";

    NetShareAdd(NULL, 2, (BYTE *)&info, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that NetShareAdd (like most of the Net* functions) is only available in a "wide" version that uses wide character strings.

Comment: it returns error such as : 1 unresolve externals and Unresolve External Symbol _NetShared@16 reference function _main

Comment: @Andro: as pointed out toward the bottom of the linked reference page, you need to link against netapi32.lib.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it would be operating system dependent; Qt's abstraction of the OS-native directory functions isn't likely to be concerned with such a thing.

You'll probably want to look into your OS' specific methods for changing the "shared" status of a directory. On Windows, this might involve using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx).